How to fix IntelliJ's database introspection hanging on startup?
I am currently running IntelliJ IDEA 2024.2 and have a Java project that includes a SQLite database.
Lately (the past few weeks or so), when opening the project, IntelliJ's introspection of the database hangs with a "loading..." message. The schemas and tables never appear and I cannot run queries from a console.
The application itself runs just fine and has no problem querying the SQLite database.
I had read that invalidating the caches in IntelliJ might help, and it did, but only the first time.
I also checked some of the IntelliJ log files, but I was not able to see anything useful (to my eyes) in terms of errors or warnings.

From JetBrains Issue Tracker issue: DBE-21315 Database tool window completely broken after the last update to 2024.2

Try closing all tabs or all tabs with datagrid (tables, query results), exit the IDE normally and start the IDE again.


Thank you.
It is worth noting that this issue will present itself again the next time the IDE is launched if it was previously closed with a datagrid tab open.
Best to close all datagrid tabs prior to closing the IDE.
Per your linked Tracker issue, the fix is expected with the next bugfix release.
